# Штаммы коронавируса писать с большой буквы?

Tags: заглавная, буква

Штаммы коронавируса писать с большой буквы? «Дельта» или «дельта»?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Рекомендация: *штамм дельта* и *дельта-штамм*.

Источник: [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=308994).